# Compiling opencv project openface

Tags: c++, cmake, opencv3.0

I am attempting to build the project OpenFace, and following the instructions from this page: https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Mac-Installation
I'm running this on a Mac with Sierra 10.12.4. All dependencies are installed. However, I am getting multiple errors when running make. I'm especially getting errors related to definition and errors related to undeclared identifiers. The entire output is pasted [here](https://codepaste.net/r62g7k).

For the redefinition error the common advice (browsing through stackoverflow) is to include header guards (which there is) or to add

```
#pragma once
```

to the header file (which I've tried). Any ideas on how I can proceed?